# FirebirdSql case insensitive

Tags: firebird2.5

Is there a way to make a FirebirdSql database case insensitive, and if not the database then a complete table?  I know about setting the CharSet to UTF8 and COLLATE UNICODE_CI on each column but wondered if there was a way to do the whole database.

Comment: Never mind, I found it.  used this script:  ALTER CHARACTER SET utf8 set default collation unicode_ci_ai

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default character set (including collation) on database [create](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-database.html)

```
CREATE {DATABASE | SCHEMA}
   ...
   [DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset [COLLATION collation]]
```

Current Firebird versions do not support altering the default character set using DDL, you would need to make a system table update if you want to do this for an existing database.

The default character set is applied on column creation if no specific character set was defined. If no default character set is specified, it is set to `NONE` (which basically means: any byte combination is valid).

Comment: for what I'm doing, the script on in my comment above works.  I create a test case.  It won't apply to any tables or columns that are already created but every column or table I create after running the script will be case insensitive.

Comment: @edepperson I actually don't know. I suspect it will only apply to columns explicitly created with `CHARACTER SET UTF8` **after** this change was made. Also take care to investigate the difference between comparisons between columns and with string literals in a query!

Comment: Correct, it does apply only to those columns created after with character set utf8.  But since I was building a new database and no columns had yet been created, this was perfect. The comparison for string literals in queries is also case insensitive